# problem with an LSTM Neural Networ, Dense Layer units

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Im having some problems getting results from my LSTM NN and would like some help.
the data Im using are CSV files of flight data.
each file is a 2d dimensional array that I label with a number(the error in that flight)
I'm running an LSTM on flight data and would like the LSTM to label each flight,meaning return a number that will represent the error in that flight.
the problem is my dense layer wont compile for any unit `enter code here`above 1.
and I understand I need it to be 10 for 10 possible numbers of labels in my data set.
this is my lstm model:

```
def train_model(self, X_train, y_train, x_val, y_val, ep):
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(LSTM(units=128, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))    
  model.add(Dense(units=10, activation='softmax'))
  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
  scores = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32,epochs=ep, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
  return scores, model
```

the error is:
ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 10) are incompatible.

the shape of X_train is 3D:(5, 199, 10)=>data files,rows in file,cols in file

the shape of y_train is:(5,)=>label for each file

thanks in advance!

Comment: y_train is incorrectly formatted. You have 5 rows containing a single object (list perhaps?) rather than 5 rows containing 10 labels each.

Comment: y is a list of 5 values,label(int) for each file.

Comment: Then dense units needs to be 5, and you need to to one-hot encode them rather than passing in just a list